# Cuda matrix multiplication

Tags: cuda, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to write a matrix multiplication code in cuda, which is pretty similar to Nvidia's cuda programming guide, but it is not working. It is supposed to do C=alpha*A*B+beta*C , but for every A,B C remains unchanged.

```
__global__ void MatMulKernel(int m,int n,int k,double *A,double *B,double *C,double alpha,double beta)
{
    double Ctemp = 0.0;
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int ind;
    for (ind = 0; ind < k; ++ind)
    {
       Ctemp += A[row+ind*m]*B[ind+col*k];
    }

   C[row+m*col] = alpha*Ctemp+beta*C[row+m*col];
//C[row+m*col] = Ctemp;
   __syncthreads();
}

extern "C" void
local_mm_cuda (const int m, const int n, const int k, const double alpha,
  const double *A, const int lda, const double *B, const int ldb,
  const double beta, double *C, const int ldc)
{

 int row, col;

  /* Verify the sizes of lda, ldb, and ldc */
  assert (lda >= m);
  assert (ldb >= k);
  assert (ldc >= m);

  // allocating memory for device array
  double *dA,*dB,*dC;
  size_t sizeA = sizeof(double)*m*k;
  size_t sizeB = sizeof(double)*n*k;
  size_t sizeC = sizeof(double)*m*n;

  cudaMalloc((void**)&dA,sizeA);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&dB,sizeB);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&dC,sizeC);

  cudaMemcpy(dA, A, sizeA, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(dB, B, sizeB, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(dC, C, sizeC, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // calling matrix multiplication kernal
  dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
  dim3 dimGrid( n/dimBlock.x, m/dimBlock.y);
  MatMulKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(m,n,k,dA,dB,dC,alpha,beta);
  cudaThreadSynchronize();

  // saving C calculated back in C
  cudaMemcpy(dC,C, sizeC,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaFree(dA);
  cudaFree(dB);
  cudaFree(dC);
}
```

Comment: What is your question? (and hint "My code isn't working" isn't a question) You have 12 API calls in that code, all return a status and you should be checking every one to see whether it returns an error. Also your code is double precision. Are you compiling for and running on a device which supports double precision?

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm missing anything obvious. I'm compiling for Tesla M2090 "Fermi" gpu

Comment: You are missing something obvious - error checking. Your symptoms are consistent with the kernel never running, but you have no way of knowing because your code doesn't check for API errors.

Comment: @talonmies yes problem was with kernel not running. I ran it on different system worked correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try to modify

```
"dim3 dimGrid( n/dimBlock.x, m/dimBlock.y);"
```

to

```
"dim3 dimGrid( (n+dimBlock.x-1)/dimBlock.x, (m+dimBlock.y-1)/dimBlock.y); "
```